# Facing Performance issues in SQL Server 2016 after migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query-performance

Recently, we migrated the servers from SQL Server 2012 to 2016. Without any changes, a few of the queries got performance degraded.

If I run the query in SQL Server 2012, it takes 10 seconds, but the same query takes 50+min in SQL Server 2016.

If I updated the SQL Server 2016 database with Legacy CE = ON then I am able to get the results very quickly as same as 2012. But I believe it's not recommended to use `Legacy CE ON` in SQL Server 2016.

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET
LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON;
```

I also updated the statistics of all tables, even thought I did get any improvement in execution.

So, Is this related to DB configuration issue (or) really do I need to update the query?

I am not sure, which configuration details I need to check. Could you please suggest anything?

Thanks advance..

Comment: Were sql2014 and 2016 configured alike and do they have same hardware configurations..what does the execution plan look like

Comment: Is it possible you were also running LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION=ON; on your 2014 instance?

Comment: @Kris, cardinality estimator is determined by database compatibility level. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/04/01/sql-server-2014s-new-cardinality-estimator-part-1/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server

Comment: Best advice I can give is to set those few queries to use old estimator "starting with SQL Server 2016 SP1, the Query Hint USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION')." to get them working again in production and then investigate the problem with the view of removing this hint.

Comment: @TheGameiswar : Yes, I have observed the execution plans - The "Top operations" are bit different in costs & added few "Index spools" in top operations. Whereas in SQL 2012, I haven't seen those spools.

Comment: You upgraded database compatibility level as well? It is safer to stagger the upgrades of SQL Server version and DB compatibility levels.

Comment: Try providing a copy of dbcc clone database if possible and also the queries

Comment: @Alex : upgraded db compatibility=130 SQL server version is 13.0.4001.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:  [**Link1**](http://www.tsql.nu/performance-tuning/optionuse-hint-new-sql-server-2016-sp1-feature/) /
[Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server)

Route cause : CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION

Thanks to all.